# Double or quit/while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I know how to use a while loop, but I'm not sure about the part where I need to make a command to double the previous score.

The task is to double or quit.

And this is my code at the moment:

```
import random
play = 'y'
Original = 1
while play.lower() == 'y':
    chance = random.randint(0,3)
    if chance == 0:
        print("Unlucky.... better luck next time")
    else:
        newnumber = Original*2
        print (newnumber)  
    play = input("Play again?[y/n]: ")
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for defining a new var newnumber, just rewrite the Original
by doing `original = original*2`

```
import random
play = 'y'
original = 1
while play.lower() == 'y':
    chance = random.randint(0,3)
    if chance == 0:
        print("Unlucky.... better luck next time")
    else:
        original = original*2
        print (original)  
    play = input("Play again?[y/n]: ")
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to bring in variable newnumber. Also, dont use mix of upper and lower case variables.

```
import random
play = 'y'
original = 1
while play.lower() == 'y':
    chance = random.randint(0,3)
    if chance == 0:
        print("Unlucky.... better luck next time")
    else:
        original= original*2 # or shorthand: original *= 2
        print (original)  
    play = input("Play again?[y/n]: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the `Original` variable to be doubled, there's no need for bringing `newNumber` into the mix. Just use 
`Original = Original * 2` (or `Original *= 2`, for short).

Answer (score 0):

You were assigning the new variable value `(original * 2)` to a locally scoped variable to the loop, so every iteration, `original` is still 1.

```
import random
play = 'y'
original = 1
while play.lower() == 'y':
    if (random.randint(0, 3) == 0):
        print('Unlucky... better luck next time')
    else:
        original *= 2; print(original)
    play = input('Play again? [y/n]: ')
```